# how to remove original points from resample curve

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to have geometry nodes know the difference between the original vertices and the "resampled" ones and create a selection mask from it. The curve isn't a standard curve however. It's a mesh that is converted into a curve after being split at the edges.

I have my reasons for this, however to do what I want, I need to be able to delete the points that correspond to the original vertices and keep only the "new" ones from the resample curve. From the example I provided this is represented by the larger points being the ones to delete (it should be obvious, but in case it is not: This is only adding a second, larger, version of the original points before resampling for the means of demonstration).

[image: fig.1]

Essentially I need to create a selection of just the larger points and use that in a delete geometry node.

Comment: I think you overlooked the [Curve to Points](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/curve_to_points.html) node looking at your node tree

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you only have to check if there are points in your original mesh whose position matches with points of your curve.

You can do this by querying the position with `Transfer Attribute`, and then using the node `Compare` (set to *Vector*).

You can then use the output of this node directly as a selection to delete the corresponding points with the node `Delete Geometry`.

[image]

*Please note: I have hidden the unnecessary sockets and options of the nodes here in the screenshot and in the file to save some space. You should just show them.*

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

---

**Update**
Unfortunately, I realized only after writing the answer that I have solved such a task before ....and in fact this is also the better solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/266739/145249

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether i don't understand what you want...or you did not understand what resample does....resample does replace your old points.

Here is the proof:

[image]

you can see i instance blue icospheres on the original curve. I instance red ones on the resampled curve.

They will be replaced as you can see...so what you want is simply default behaviour.

[image]

the original curve has 6 vertices.

The resampled one 10.

Comment: i know what the resample curve does in practice, not so much how it works in code. the fact remains though that i need a way to remove specific points from the curve that happen to coincide with the vertices of the original input mesh. thx for the input though :)