# Geometry Nodes - Distribute Points equidistantly on each edge of mesh (with Points on every Vertex)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to place Points evenly (approximately every 1,1 meters for example) on the edge of my mesh.

I managed to place them exactly every 1,1m but I want to keep a **Point on every corner**. The distance between 2 points on every edge should be the same, and close to 1,1m.
[image: Nodes]

[image: Here is what I get for now]

I drew what I want :
[image: What I want]

Here, if an edge is 4 meters long, it should be divided in 4 segments of 1 meter each.

Any idea of how to do this ?
Thanks a lot in advance !

[EDIT]

More explanations :
Foreach of my edges, I would like to have :

- a Point at the start
- a Point at the end
- a Points every (approximately 1m10)

For example, on an edge of 4 meters, there should be 5 Points from start to end with 1m between each.
If the next edge is 5m8, there should be 6 points with 1,16m between each.

The math/logic behind this is :

- Edge length = 5,80m
- 5,80m / 1,10m = 5,2727
- Round(5,2727) = 5
- There should be 5 sub-edges on my edge.
- As they must have the same length, they must be (5,80m/5 =) 1,16m long.

Hope this is clearer :)

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite understand this question, because it involves a contradiction: how can the points along an edge be evenly spaced at 1.1m, and at the same time have the same distance to the corners? That would work for a square, but not for the shape you show. Can you explain this in a little more detail?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I added some examples in original post !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick here is to first separate the individual edges of the mesh *(ngon, not triangulated!)*, because then the individual segments can be divided separately.

[image]

[image]

1. First I remove unnecessary faces with `Delete Geometry`.
2. Next, this is the crucial point, separate the edges with `Split Edges`.
3. Then you only need to convert the remaining edges to curves with `Mesh to Curve`.
4. These individual segments can then be subdivided with the node `Resample Curve` as you wish.

**UPDATE**:

Since this method also doubles the corners, you can also use the following nodes if you want to instantiate objects at the points:

[image]

Here I instantiate cubes at the corner points, and icospheres at the segments in between.

Note that I use a selection (inverted endpoint selection) for the spheres that excludes the corner points.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks a lot ! This looks awesome, i'll try that as soon as I can. I understand everything except one thing : why would you need to extrude ans delete geometry right After ?

Comment: @ArthurBellemin I'm terribly sorry that was actually an artifact that crept in here is of course not necessary. ;-) Well recognized! Thank you! You just have to delete the faces, of course. I have just updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you ! Not home this weekend, but I'll try this and validate your answer during next week ☺️

Comment: Thanks again, I managed to get this working with your help ! I'm working on a modular house :)
https://imgur.com/a/CSDNd97